# System.Data.dll not available in .NET <4

Tags: .net, dll

I recently started a job primarily maintaining existing code. They have me running Windows 7 x64 on a virtual machine (to tunnel into the client network) and Visual Studio 2012.

When I try to compile any code that uses `System.Data`, the system cannot find it, unless I change the assembly to .NET 4 or higher. Many of these projects were originally compiled in .NET 2.0, and have been around for years, so I know that the DLL should be there.

I am going to have to convert any project I try to touch - if I can't compile, I can't test properly - and many of them are pretty old and quite useful, so they are heavily intertwined (if I change one from .NET 2.0, ALL projects that reference that DLL have to be changed to .NET 4 or better)

When I try to re-install .NET 3.5 or earlier, Windows 7 wants me to just enable or disable .NET 3.5.1. Based on what I've read, that includes all previous versions.

Is this something that I can fix? All I find, when searching for answers, involve other DLLs deeper in the namespace (i.e., `System.Data.SqlClient`). If I could just download the DLL for each version (or just v2.0) then I could just add that as reference and be done...

Comment: System.Data is not something that you can istall or download from somewhere. It is a base part of the framework. By the way, if you need NET2.0 why do you try to install 3.5?

Comment: So, did you enable the .NET 3.5 feature?

Comment: @Steve In various projects, it is assembled under anything from .NET 2.0 to 3.5 - I would like to use the newest version without changing the assembly version. Unless version 2.0 is the most stable and complete version...

Comment: @DanielMann Yes, it's enabled

Comment: The compiler uses the *reference assembly*, it is stored in the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 directory.  Have a look-see if it is there.  You could copy it from another machine if it is not.

Comment: @HansPassant You hit it on the nail - the DLL was missing from that directory. I copied it from my main machine, and it just _worked_. Thanks! As for marking an answer, I have too little rep to even upvote your comment...